# Golang struct type conversion

Tags: go, struct, interface, casting

I'm trying to figure out how go handles type conversion between structs. Everything I have read tells me that types with the same underlying type are considered compatible and type conversion happens implicitly. If that is the case, why does the code below not work? Both `Foo` and `Bar` implement the `FooI` interface, and they both add an `x` property of type string. Yet, when I pass a struct of type `Bar` to `AcceptBarOrFoo` that expects a struct of type `Foo`, I get a type mismatch compile error.

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/duc_L7nj2HF)

```golang
package main

import (
    "play.ground/bar"
    "play.ground/foo"
)

func main() {
    AcceptBarOrFoo(bar.Bar{})
}

func AcceptBarOrFoo(foo.Foo) interface{} {
    return nil
}

// -- iface/iface.go --

package iface

type FooI interface {
    a() string
    b(int) int
}
// -- foo/foo.go --
package foo

import (
    "play.ground/iface"
)

type Foo struct {
    iface.FooI
    x string
}
// -- bar/bar.go --
package bar

import (
    "play.ground/iface"
)

type Bar struct {
    iface.FooI
    x string
}
```

Comment: Interfaces are only polymorphic when you are *assigning directly* to an interface value. They do not bestow any broader ideas of polymorphism in the language. `foo.Foo` is a struct type.

Comment: There are no higher order types in Go. Just consult the spec, it is explaines type conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foo's `x` is different from Bar's `x` because non-exported identifiers are never equal across package boundaries. Fix by [exporting](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the fields in foo.Foo and bar.Bar:

```
type Foo struct {
    iface.FooI
    X string // <-- start with capital letter to export
}
```

To use a foo.Foo or bar.Bar as an argument value, a foo.Foo and bar.Bar must be [assignable](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) to the argument's type. It does not work to use foo.Foo as the argument type because named types are not assignable to each other. However, named types are assignable to unnamed types when the two types share the same underlying type.  Declare the argument as an unnamed type:

```
func AcceptBarOrFoo(struct {
    iface.FooI
    X string
}) interface{} {
    return nil
}
```

With these changes, the following code compiles:

```
AcceptBarOrFoo(bar.Bar{})
AcceptBarOrFoo(foo.Foo{})
```

[Run the example on the Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/LaZ6-Yg_d7b)

Another option is to use a [conversion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) to a common type. In the following code, foo.Foo is the common type and bar.Bar is converted to a foo.Foo.

```
func Accept(foo.Foo) interface{} {
    return nil
}

... 

Accept(foo.Foo{})
Accept(foo.Foo(bar.Bar{}))
```

[Run the example on the Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/pTGHhaC4S3L).

Note: foo.Foo and bar.Bar must have the same fields for the above to work (field names are exported, fields in same order, fields have same types).

---

Some notes about Go:

- There are [conversions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) from one concrete type to another.
- Go is famous for having no implicit conversions in expressions, but there are implicit conversions in some [assignment](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability) scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert one concrete type to another concrete type, ever. They are not the same. There is no way to define this type of automatic casting in Go. At best, you could define a function that accepts a `Bar` and builds and returns a new `Foo` with its fields set to the same values as the input `Bar`.

> Everything I have read tells me that if the underlying types are the same, the higher order types are considered compatible and type conversion happens implicitly

It's unclear what your source for this is, but *nothing* would have ever stated or implied this, it's simply not true. Go does **no** implicit conversion, of anything. That's a big, loudly advertised feature of Go. Given `type Foo struct { a int }` and `type Bar struct { a int }`, you can never assign an object of type `Bar` to a variable of type `Foo`.

You *can* convert from either concrete type to an interface type, when the type satisfies the interface. Your `AcceptBarOrFoo` method should accept an interface type (which both `Foo` and `Bar` satisfy), not a concrete type. Given that interfaces only define methods (not members), and given neither `Foo` or `Bar` have any methods, your interface would be the empty interface, `interface{}`. The value passed in would serve no purpose, except for you to later convert it back to a concrete type to access its members, but that's not really what interfaces are for.

Comment: I've found many similar articles that suggest the same as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613271/golang-is-conversion-between-different-struct-types-possible. I now understand the nuances that had me confused before. Being new to the language, I found the spec helpful but struggled to interpret exactly what was meant in much of the types section.